# Can't retrieve data from Pandas DF, can't replace values in column in Pandas DF

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary, replace

I'm working with `adult.data.csv` https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

I wrote this code:

```
data  = pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv', sep = ";")
data[data['salary'] == '>50K']['marital-status'].count()
```

I get a result of 0.

I also tried to replace values in columns with script:

```
data[data['marital-status'].replace({'Divorced': 0, 'Never-married': 0, 'Separeted': 0, 'Widiwed': 0, 'Married-civ-spouse': 1, 'Married-spose-absent': 1, 'Married-AF-spose': 1})
```

I've got = nan

Answer (score 0):

you probably shouldn't use `sep=';'` since the file is separated by ',' not ';'.

And you should set column name while reading the csv:

```
pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv', header=None, names=columns_names)
```

where columns_name is a list of str.

Comment: Without sep = ";" - it's not working at all. Probably I should resave csv file?

Comment: yes; maybe try re-downloading the file and rename it as .csv and try again. because it workds for

Comment: I tried to count int and float data and it works. So my problem only with object data. Maybe someone have any idea about it? Thanks to ABS for your help

Comment: Find intresting desicion for converting 'object' to 'float' / 'int': df['User_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(df.User_Score, errors='coerce'). Maybe will be useful for someone